# Why would Laal Singh Chaddha wear leg braces?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, laal-singh-chaddha

In [Laal Singh Chaddha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laal_Singh_Chaddha), Laal would wear leg braces in his childhood. In one scene, while wearing leg braces, doctor was telling to Laal's mother that Laal doesn't have problem with his legs but in his brain.
If Laal didn't have problem with his legs, then why would his mother compel him to wear leg braces? Whether she wanted to take an excuse for his mental health problem or any other reason?

Comment: Maybe they tried to actually write something on their own and not copy from Forrest Gump. :-D